# Stretch specific grid's row to fit browser's height

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm having this problem and I can't figure it out yet, maybe you guys can help me.

I have to stretch a specific row (may by any of them) of a css grid to fit all screen's height, but the others just have to fit self content.

I'm able to stretch the last row, but no previous ones.

In the following code I need to stretch the first row leaving the second one at the bottom of the screen.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktNMd.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Ugw.png)

```
<div id="MAIN_GRID" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr; grid-template-rows: auto;">
<div style="padding: 3px; grid-column: 1 / 2; grid-row-end: 1; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: rgb(168, 93, 167);">
    <div id="TOP_FORM" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr); grid-template-rows: auto;">
        <div style="padding: 3px; grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; visibility: hidden;">
            <input>
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 3px; grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; visibility: hidden;">
                <input>
                </div>
                <div style="padding: 3px; grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: rgb(99, 5, 218);">text</div>
                <div style="padding: 3px; grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: rgb(53, 22, 215);">button</div>
                <div style="padding: 3px; grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">button</div>
                <div style="padding: 3px; grid-area: 1 / 4 / 3 / 6; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: rgb(191, 48, 252);">button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 3px; grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: rgb(146, 3, 131);">
            <div id="OUTPUT_FORM" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); grid-template-rows: auto;">
                <div style="padding: 3px; grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; visibility: hidden;">
                    <input>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding: 3px; grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: rgb(237, 178, 155);">textarea</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite your strange and complex placements, your main gird has only 2 elements, and you want to place them one above the other, without changing the order, which is the default behavior of grid layout. So just remove any grid related properties on these 2 children.

Then on the main grid itself you can give it full height with `height: 100%`, and play with `grid-template-rows` to give the children the vertical size you want.